# How to use a default in a correct way

Tags: python

Given the following function:

```
def httpstatus(self, url, data=None, timeout=None):
    if timeout is None:
        timeout = socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    urlopen(url, data, timeout)
```

The timeout parameter should be optional. But if ommited I would like to use the socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT value as shown in code. However, that one is a protected member. And that doesn't seems the right way. So different approach...

```
def httpstatus(self, url, data=None, timeout=None):
    if timeout is None:
        urlopen(url, data)
    else:
        urlopen(url, data, timeout)
```

Yack that one is even more dirty...

What is the right and proper way to fall back to the socket default timeout?

Comment: If you're wrapping `urllib2.urlopen`, why don't you just use `*args` and `**kwargs`: `def httpstatus(self, *args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: @Blender I'm sure he's not just wrapping it and that was just a minimal example…

Comment: @blender, for now I'm just wrapping, but I was curious in a more general way what a good approach is. Maybe I shouldn't look for a general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`**`-syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for that:

```
def httpstatus(self, url, data=None, timeout=None):
    kwargs = {}
    if timeout is not None:
        kwargs['timeout'] = timeout
    urlopen(url, data, **kwargs)
```

Or even:

```
def httpstatus(self, url, data=None, **kwargs):
    # Don't forget to mention in documentation that all
    # extra arguments are passed to urlopen as is.
    urlopen(url, data, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The first variant you wrote seems to me much less obvious, less readable, more likely to go wrong, and generally worse than the final version that the OP submitted.  The second version is not great either, because the caller of httpstatus() should not need to know what its implementation is, specifically that the caller can, if he wants, add urlopen() parameters (how will he know that, given the generally dismal lack of documentation in Python source?)

Comment: @jamond Well, you are partially right: the issue with the second version you mentioned really exists. But its common in Python to just mentioned in your docs that all extra arguments are passed to some library function.

Comment: @jarmod, can you explain: that the caller can add urlopen() parameters... I've read it 5 times over but still missing the point here.

Comment: @jamond The `if`-way is OK if the code is exactly as shown, but I'm sure that's just an example. There will be a lot of stuff going on before the actual call to `urlopen` and at the point the call is actually made it's already unclear what was going on; you even might end up with a number of `if`-branches.

Comment: @Paul well, in this particular case this can't happen. But imagine that `urlopen` has another parameter, say, `do_bad_thing` ans if it is set to `True` it does a bad thing. In my second example user of your function might also pass this bad argument to `urlopen` through your function.

Comment: Oke, yep no it see it... **kwargs delivers everything passed on... and now httpstatus is 1 on 1 with urlopen. Yep that's def. not right. But still... what if I have three optionals... a triple if with 8 branches....

Comment: @Paul Note that it delivers _everything_ only in the second case. In my first example it delivers only what you explicitly put there.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the first version, I've used this pattern many times (in more complicated functions, with several extra arguments).

Comment: @kirelagin, yes I understood that's only the case with your second solution.

Comment: @kirelagin I'd prefer a number of if branches.  I prefer explicit code to implicit code.  Using kwargs completely hides the fact that part of the interface to this method is 'timeout'.  What if the implementation changes to use something other than urlopen() or urlopen itself changes so that 'timeout' is no longer a parameter?  You also cannot grep through the code easily and find out that timeout is relevant here, it's just all hidden away, and unnecessarily so,imo.

Comment: @jarmod Well, again, you are right. But everything you said in your last comment doesn't apply to my first example, does it?

Comment: @kirelagin, no it only applies to your second suggestion.

Comment: @kirelagin No, but we could go on like this all day ;-)  I'm happy to see that you added documentation to the second alternative.  But now what if you want some kwargs for another function call in addition to urlopen().  And let's say that function shares one or parameter names with urlopen(), so now the kwargs are accidentally sent to multiple functions.  It just becomes a big mess, unnecessarily.  My preference is to provide an explicit interface to the user, regardless of how you ultimately implement it.  I would go with the OPs 'different approach' personally.

Comment: @jarmod I think you are in a different time-zone, I would be night for me.. ;-) but anyway thanks a lot you both for the insights you have given me.

Comment: @jarmod Well, I've just suggested one of the many options ans the author of the question just learned something from my answer, isn't that great? ;) One can always choose whatever he likes and whatever works better in particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If you really dont want to use protected var, just take number from socket and comment from where you get it:

```
# settings
default_timeout = 100 # socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
```

another option is to use `getattr` with default value:

```
default_timeout = getattr(socket, '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT', 100)

def httpstatus(self, url, data=None, timeout=default_timeout):
    urlopen(url, data, timeout)
```

Comment: It seems odd to use a protected member, or is that not uncommon in Python?

Comment: @Paul you want to use it anyway... so where to use it does not matter much i think. You can make some module/class option equal to this protected socket var and use your local var in function definition.

Comment: Yep you've got a valid point there, I do want to use it. Also that default is not going away from the socket library as well as the parameter sequence of the urlopen.

Comment: @Paul Well, there is no such thing as _protected_ member in Python. They politely call them _non-public_ =). And it's definitely a bad idea to use them. PEP-8 clearly says that they are not intended to be used by third-parties (that is, by you).

Comment: don't know who is pressing the -1 buttons here... not me for sure

Comment: I think you are right, just steer away from the default and hand over my own sane default.